# No display for drop down menu

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu

Hello I just want to display a drop down menu to choose the time to publish an article in my backoffice. So I've created a special field in my table 'articles' with the type 'time'. I work on cakephp framework. Here's the code :

```
<?php $this->Form->create(null, array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'))) ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->inputs(array('Article.publication_time'/*, array('label' => 'Time')); ?>
<?php $this->Form->end('Submit') ?>
```

This code display a simple text input. Can you explain me why?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code

```
echo $this->Form->input('Article.publication_time', array('type'=>'date',
   'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 
   'minYear' => date('Y') - 70,
   'maxYear' => date('Y') ,
 ));
```

Comment: Yes ok thank you very much I forgot the 'type' tag. Have a good day!